# [rospack] Error: stack/package rqt_gui not found

Tags: ros, rqt-gui, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working on part 6 "Understanding ROS Topics" of the tutorial and I am having a problem with section 1.2.1.  I am running Ubuntu 12.04 with Fuerte and when I try to run

rosrun rqt_gui rqt_gui

It gives me an error saying rqt_gui was not found.  I am not sure why I am missing this package or how to fix it.  I tried reinstalling python-catkin-pkg, but that did not fix the issue.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this so I can continue with the tutorial?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50321/%5Brospack%5D-error:-stack/package-rqt_gui-not-found/) by [robotnik23](https://answers.ros.org/users/3777/robotnik23/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-12-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robotnik23](https://answers.ros.org/users/3777/robotnik23/) on 2012-12-15**:
It seems like I am in fact missing rqt_gui, but when I attempt to update apt-get and then install ros_fuerte_rqt I get the error unable to locate package ros_fuerte_rqt

**Comment by [robotnik23](https://answers.ros.org/users/3777/robotnik23/) on 2012-12-15**:
Nevermind I figured it out.  Dashes instead of underscores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to have rqt_gui installed. You can mke sure it is installed by running:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros_fuerte_rqt
```

In ROS Groovy, replace

```
$ rosrun rqt_gui rqt_gui
```

with

```
$ rqt
```

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2